# Modal triggering using bootstrap since it is getting triggered after focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery

learning bootstrap 4 and trying to call the modal popup when the input on change event but not sure whether that will be a correct solution or not.

Once I delete the existing text from the input, that should trigger the modal automatically after the last text deletion. Currently, this is getting triggered once I click out of the input box.

```js
if ($("input[id$='CheckboxPhone']").is(":checked")) {
  $('.testing').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
      //call bootstrap modal, for testing we will call alert
      alert("test");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="testing" class="testing" value="2144566189" data-value="214-456-6189">

  <form class="form-test">
    <div class="checkbox m-l-20 m-t-sm-10">
      <input type="checkbox" id="customerServiceCheckboxPhone"             name="customerServiceCheckboxPhone" checked="checked" class="js-test valid">
      <label class="checkbox-check" tabindex="0" for="customerServiceCheckboxPhone"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox m-l-20 m-t-sm-10">
      <input type="checkbox" id="offersCheckboxPhone" name="customerServiceCheckboxPhone" checked="checked" class="js-test valid">
      <label class="checkbox-check" tabindex="0" for="offersCheckboxPhone"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox m-l-20 m-t-sm-10">
      <input type="checkbox" id="testCheckboxPhone" name="customerServiceCheckboxPhone" checked="checked" class="js-test valid">
      <label class="checkbox-check" tabindex="0" for="testCheckboxPhone"></label>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `change` event happens after a blur, not before (typically).  If you want it to happen immediately on change use the `input` event instead

Comment: @Taplar input event? I would recommend to use `on('keypress'`

Comment: @SalminSkenderovic https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Comment: @SalminSkenderovic also, keypress has been deprecated.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeypress

Comment: @Taplar I have missed this. Thank you!

Comment: @taplar but how do I know when the last character is deleted? because that's what my question is.

When anyone checkbox is checked, and when i tried to delete the number, then it should show the modal/alert

Comment: Your logic already has a val().length < 1 check for that

Comment: An added side note; if this logic binds the event handler, if the user unchecks the checkbox, it is not going to automatically unbind the event handler.  The event handler will still exist and execute.

Comment: @Taplar, thanks, working. Can you write an answer so that I can close this question?

Comment: It's already closed.